# Efficient printwriting & minor issues

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to print phone number to a file and just wondering how to make it more efficient. Right now, the time it takes for my program to write 28 phone numbers is 12.5seconds. I wonder if anyone could guide me to lower the runtime. Here's my print Method:

```
<code removed>
```

As you can see, I have to reset scanner every time since it gives me the order of list contrary to what I want.(I also need help on fixing this). For example: if I  change the while loop to this:

I get this result:

```
expected result:                              actual result: 
TEL: 2475463                                  247 : AHR 
2475463 : AIRLINE                             247 : AHS
247 : AHR                                     TEL: 2475463
247 : AHS                                     2475463 : AIRLINE
--------                                      --------
```

I appreciate all your help and understanding.

Comment: What does `isMatch()` look like? What does the input text look like, and what does its format mean for the operation of your program?

Comment: Also, what is the meaning of the `main()` input parameters `str`, `str1`, and `str2`?

Comment: Also you're calling `.printf()` with a format string that expects 3 arguments, but you're only passing 2 arguments.

Comment: here's the full code: http://ideone.com/d2IGwj

Comment: @Pointy No, `%n` is newline (and not a format argument).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ah durr OK. It would have given a runtime error so I was a little perplexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file once. Store the words in a `List<String> words` like,

```
static List<String> getWords(String fileName) {
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);) {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String line = scanner.next();
            al.add(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return al;
}

static final List<String> words = getWords("word_list.txt");
```

Then your method can iterate `words` as many times as you like (and be called without re-reading `words`) which should fix your performance issues. Finally, I would suggest [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
public static void print(String str, String str1, String str2)
        throws java.io.IOException {

    // output file name
    try (FileWriter output = new FileWriter("result.txt", true);
            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(output))) {

        write.println("TEL: " + str);
        for (String line : words) {
            if (isMatch(str, line))
                write.printf("%s : %s %n", str, line);
        }
        for (String line : words) {
            if (isMatch(str1, line))
                write.printf("%s : %s %n", str1, line);
        }
        for (String line : words) {
            if (isMatch(str2, line))
                write.printf("%s : %s %n", str2, line);
        }

        write.println("--------");
    }
}
```

**Edit**

It would be less efficient (you asked for more remember) but you could read it into a `String` (once) and then use a [`Scanner(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) like

```
static String readFile(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);) {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String line = scanner.next();
            sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

static final String words = readFile("word_list.txt");

public static void print(String str, String str1, String str2)
        throws java.io.IOException {

    // output file name
    try (FileWriter output = new FileWriter("result.txt", true);
            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(output))) {

        write.println("TEL: " + str);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(words);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (isMatch(str, line))
                write.printf("%s : %s %n", str, line);
        }
        scanner = new Scanner(words);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line1 = scanner.nextLine();
            if (isMatch(str1, line1))
                write.printf("%s : %s %n", str1, line1);
        }
        scanner = new Scanner(words);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line2 = scanner.nextLine();
            if (isMatch(str2, line2))
                write.printf("%s : %s %n", str2, line2);
        }

        write.println("--------");
    }
}
```

This is less efficient because we reconstruct the `Scanner` to parse the lines for every test.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I could use ArrayList. Is there other way to approach this problem by just working with the current code?

Comment: @ArcRanges Edited to give you an example that reads `String` instead. Next time, please give us all the requirements in your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

1) Scann the file once! Use a List to store the lines and when it is finished proceed with your logic

2) as you are calling it several times think about a "bulk writing" (method accepts Lists of Strings instead of just Strings, so you only need to open/close the file once)